# reasonable way to perform ajax requests with setInterval

Tags: jquery, ajax, server

I am making a sample social media site and I want to know how to make a load-friendly way to check for new posts, etc. with ajax. The best I can think of is this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    // Code...
  })
}, 1000);
```

However, this would create a lot of strain on the server, and I wondered if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to check the server every second for new (...) without talking to the server every second? That's quite impossible. Websockets might be an option for you, but otherwise this kind of polling is your best option.

Comment: Can your site use HTML5 only? I mean without falling back to long-polling (the above method) IF thats the case you can user Server Sent Events

Comment: Consider changing to `setTimeout` in AJAX `.always` handler, instead of `setInterval` in order to avoid redundant requests. I mean, make it work like **send AJAX - response processed - wait 1 second - send AJAX - response processed - wait 1 second...**.